# Where clause inside where clause?

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, yii2, where-clause

I am using Yii 2.0 PHP framework. Is it possible to put where clauses inside a where clause? In my case, I want to put `orwhere` clauses inside `andwhere`:

```
$employees = Employee::find()
    ->where([ 'parent' => new \MongoId($session['company_owner']) ])
    ->andwhere([ Employee::find()
        ->orwhere([ 'employee_id' => new \MongoRegex("/".$keyword."/i") ])
        ->orwhere([ 'department_name' => new \MongoId($departments['_id']) ])
        ->orwhere([ 'division_name' => new \MongoId($divisions['_id']) ])
        ->orwhere([ 'job_title' => new \MongoId($jobpositions['_id']) ])
    ])->all();
```

The code above returns this error:

[image]

It's because it's not the correct syntax/structure, I think.
Anyway, here's my original code:

```
$employees = Employee::find()
    ->orwhere([ 'employee_id' => new \MongoRegex("/".$keyword."/i") ])
    ->orwhere([ 'department_name' => new \MongoId($departments['_id']) ])
    ->orwhere([ 'division_name' => new \MongoId($divisions['_id']) ])
    ->orwhere([ 'job_title' => new \MongoId($jobpositions['_id']) ])
    ->andwhere([ 'parent' => new \MongoId($session['company_owner']) ])
    ->all();
```

It's working fine, but I want to restructure it since it takes time. It still has to go through that series of `orwhere`'s before getting to `andwhere`. That's why I tried restructuring the query but it's not working.

Do you have any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this :

```
$employees = Employee::find()
    ->where([ 'parent' => new \MongoId($session['company_owner']) ])
    ->andwhere([
        'or',
        [ 'employee_id' => new \MongoRegex("/".$keyword."/i") ],
        [ 'department_name' => new \MongoId($departments['_id']) ],
        [ 'division_name' => new \MongoId($divisions['_id']) ],          
        [ 'job_title' => new \MongoId($jobpositions['_id']) ],
    ])->all();
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where()-detail

Comment: this works fine, it's just that there are some brackets and parenthesis missing, I'll edit your answer. thank you!